# azure data factory: Linked services parameterization (making linked service dynamic)

Tags: dynamic, parameters, connection, azure-data-factory

Scenario: In a multi-tenant architecture, I have the same batch job (ETL) running for multiple clients (tenant-wise). In this case only variable is source and target. In ADF my pipes/mapping-data-flows are statc, the dynamic things are LinkedServices. Even datasets also can be static, because I am expecting same tables in sources and targets  across clients.

### How can I make LinkedServices dynamic?

This is how I implemented it through Scripts (shell, python).
- A wrapper script will be initiated with client_code as a parameter
- client's DB details and connection details will be available in a DB, get it from there
- ETL job (script) will be initiated with the respective client's source n target DB details
- Logging/ auditing is done at all steps

How can I achieve this through ADF?

Comment: Please refer this link as well, the purpose may be slightly different.  https://mrpaulandrew.com/2019/06/18/azure-data-factory-web-hook-vs-web-activity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameterize your linked service and pass dynamic values at run time. To achieve your goal, you have to add a parameter to your linked service and parameterize the server name in the linked service definition.

[Parameterize linked services](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer from Timo, what wasn't clear to me immediately was how to set the parameter values at run time. The answer is to add parameters on the Dataset for each of the parameters you created on the Linked Service. Here is an example where I plan to connect to a series of Oracle servers:
[image: Dataset parameter configuration]

[image: Dataset Linked Service configuration]